# How to Add two multi-dimensional std::vectors (without using operator+)?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, stdvector

The algorithm is simple and straight-forward:
Keep break the `n` dimensional vector into `n-1` dimensional constituent vectors, until you have access to the basic-datatype objects. Their addition is simple and well-defined.

Here is my implementation using templates and `operator+`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<class T>
std::vector<T> operator+ (const std::vector<T>& v1, const std::vector<T>& v2)
{
    std::vector<T> output;
    unsigned len = v1.size();
    output.resize(len);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        output[i] = v1[i] + v2[i];
    return output;
}

int main ()
{
    using namespace std;

    vector<std::vector<int>> x = {{8,9,0},{5,6,7}};
    vector<std::vector<int>> y = {{1,1,1},{1,1,1}};

    auto result = x + y; // Yeah, just like that !

    // Being Lazy, instead of implementing multi-dimensional vector printing...
    for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); ++i)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<result[i].size(); ++j)
            cout << result.at(i).at(j) << " ";
        cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

**But suppose you are not allowed to use `operator+`.

You have to design an interface as some function `Add()`.**

But I'm unable to do so!! Here's my attempt:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// Hoping to handle vectors...
template<class T>
std::vector<T> Add (const std::vector<T>& v1, const std::vector<T>& v2)
{
    std::vector<T> output;
    unsigned len = v1.size();
    output.resize(len);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        output[i] = Add(v1[i], v2[i]);
    return output;
}

// Hoping to handle basic-datatypes...
template<class T>
T Add (const T& v1, const T& v2)
{
    T output;
    unsigned len = v1.size();
    output.resize(len);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        output[i] = v1[i] + v2[i];
    return output;
}

int main ()
{
    using namespace std;

    vector<std::vector<int>> x = {{8,9,0},{5,6,7}};
    vector<std::vector<int>> y = {{1,1,1},{1,1,1}};

    auto result = Add(x, y); // I wish ! But not happening !

    // Being Lazy, instead of implementing multi-dimensional vector printing...
    for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); ++i)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<result[i].size(); ++j)
            cout << result.at(i).at(j) << " ";
        cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Is it even possible?**

Comment: And this is why you use a single dimension array/vector and fake that it has multiple dimensions using math.  That way you can have a n dimensional vector but only use a single for loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must provide a version for `Add()` that works on basic data types

```
// Handle basic-datatypes
template<class T>
T Add(const T& x1, const T& x2)
{
  return x1 + x2;
}

// Specialisation for vectors
template<class T>
std::vector<T> Add(std::vector<T> const& v1, std::vector<T> const& v2)
{
  assert(v1.size()==v2.size());
  std::vector<T> result;
  result.reserve(v1.size());
  for(size_t i=0; i!=v1.size(); ++i)
    result.emplace_back(Add(v1[i],v2[i])); // possibly recursive
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
// Hoping to handle basic-datatypes...
template<class T>
T Add (const T& v1, const T& v2)
{
    T output;
    unsigned len = v1.size();
    output.resize(len);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        output[i] = v1[i] + v2[i];
    return output;
}
```

It has to be:

```
// Hoping to handle basic-datatypes...
template<class T>
T Add (const T& v1, const T& v2)
{
    return v1 + v2;
}
```

---

Also the one which handles `basic-datatypes` must come before the one which handles `vector`s.

Comment: Although OP in this case is this very person :)